# Bare metal without global operator new

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, embedded, bare-metal

Consider safety software, where dynamic allocation in general is disallowed and exceptions are disallowed. Dynamic allocation is allowed only when class explicity defines operator `new` and `delete`. Using operator `new` for others class should cause compilation failure.

The simplest way to cause compilation failure in described situation is to remove global new operator:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t) = delete;
```

On the one hand this cause side effects with standard library. For example including `<array>` propagates inclusion to `<new_allocator>` by `<stdexcept>`. `<new_allocator>` uses `::new` operator and this cause build fail even when You don't want to use exception and memory allocation. According to Scoot Meyers `<array>` should be bare metal friendly.

On the other hand this cause error with compiler built-in operator

```
src/main.cpp:91:31: error: deleted definition of 'void* operator new(std::size_t)'
 void* operator new(std::size_t) = delete;                               ^
<built-in>: note: previous declaration of 'void* operator new(std::size_t)'
```

Is there any solution to ban `::new` and use `<array>`?

Is there any solution to ban `::new` globally **at all**?

Comment: Are you ok with an error that occurs a bit later, at link time?

Comment: @Marc I am ok with any solution that fails the build at all.

Comment: There are good reasons for C sometimes. This sounds like one of them. C does not generate hidden overhead. `new` is not the only problem, but inerhitance can also result in trouble, e.g. for interrupt handlers and other time-critical paths.

Comment: This would be one reason why C++ isn't often used for such systems. In fact, safety critical software often requires that verified libraries are used, which effectively excludes most of `std::` from your average embedded systems compiler.

Comment: @Olaf inheritance has very little to no performance impact on interrupt handlers.   It's either 0-1 cycles of overhead to call a virtual function (on the ARM, anyways) compared to a statically linked function.

Comment: @RussSchultz: Where did I say overhead would be the problem? The problem is deterministic behaviour. With virtual functions, you easily can call functions you never intended to or even thought about. Said that: on typical embedded systrems, the overhead for th additional indirection very well matters. For the STM32F for example Flash can require more than 8 or 10 addiitional clock cycles. The small "cache" often cannot catch this situation; less as it is a data-access which also can interfere with prefetch. As I wrote: **trouble**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use GCC and GNU LD, then I think you can just add `--wrap=malloc` to your linker flags. As global `::new` uses `malloc()` internally, all calls to `malloc()` in your application will be replaced with `__wrap_malloc()`. If this function is undefined, then the linking will fail.

Another, possibly simpler option, is to add `ASSERT(DEFINED(malloc) == 0, "Dynamic allocation used!");` to your linker script. This will assert that `malloc()` is not defined.

Neither of these options protect you from redefining global `::new` to use some other form of global allocation. You could do the same for global symbol `::new` in the linker script, but its name is mangled (in here `_Znwj`), so this will be a little strange...

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what programming language you use:

On any sound, bare-metal system, you simply remove the `.heap` segment from the linker script entirely. Any code relying on dynamic allocation will then fail to link. And you won't have to allocate RAM for a segment that you weren't going to use anyway.

Comment: This solution would work only on some platforms, where `new` and/or `malloc()` depend of the presence of such section. In many platforms you don't need that section, and all systems using newlib as the libc just need you to implement your own `_sbrk_r()` function, which has nothing to do with such section.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I want to emphasize:

1. Inclusion of exception related headers with their definitions should not bother you if the exceptions don't find their way into your code.
2. When you disable the exceptions, you cannot use them in your code (the compilation will fail if you do). However, it doesn't remove usage of exceptions from standard library. The standard library may contain pre-compiled versions of template classes, such as `std::string` (i.e. `std::basic_string<char, ...>`) or `std::streambuf` (i.e. `std::basic_streambuf<char, ...>`), and when you use it in your code, the compiler doesn't try to instantiate the templates, it just reuses the pre-compiled version with exceptions.

In order to have much better control over your code I strongly recommend to exclude standard library altogether using `-nostdlib` compilation option with G++ compiler. It won't prevent your from using various template classes, such as `std::array` from STL, it will just exclude the whole C++ library and runtime for you.

I also recommend reading [Practical Guide to Bare Metal C++](https://www.gitbook.com/book/arobenko/bare_metal_cpp/details). It may give a bit of deeper insight into C++ bare-metal internals.

Comment: BTW - exactly because of item nr 2 I have compiled my own toolchain for ARM microcontrollers, where C++ exceptions are properly disabled for the whole libstdc++ - https://github.com/FreddieChopin/bleeding-edge-toolchain