# Automatic memory pool feature by template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, memory-management

A continuation of a [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426411/bare-metal-without-global-operator-new).

Consider safety software, where dynamic allocation with fragmentation is disallowed. Dynamic allocation is allowed only when class explicity defines operator `new` and `delete` to avoid fragmentation.

Now here we have a chance to optimize explicit definition of operator `new` and `delete` for any class we want to get. At the first glance, template class from  which any class can inherit is the simplest and clearest way to use for the end user.

```
template<class T, unsigned size>
class MemoryPool
{
private:
    struct Pool
    {
        bool    allocated         __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
        uint8_t memory[sizeof(T)] __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
    };
    static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(Pool)], size> memoryPool;

public:
    void* operator new(std::size_t) noexcept
    {
        T* ret = nullptr;
        for(auto it = memoryPool.begin(); it != memoryPool.end(); ++it)
        {
           /* ... */
        } 
        return ret;
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
    {
        for(auto it = memoryPool.begin(); it != memoryPool.end(); ++it)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
};
```

If it were a fairy tale, declaration of class with MemoryPool would be sweet.

```
class Interface
{/*...*/};

class Foo : public Interface,  MemoryPool<Foo, 8>
{/*...*/};

class Bar : public Interface
{/*...*/};
```

And declaration of objects:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(); // goes to dedicated memory pool
Bar* bar = new Bar(); // fails on build
```

But even when `static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(Pool)], size> memoryPool;` is static and will go outside of the class, so it will not change the size of a class, the compiler complains that `Foo` is incomplete and can't deduce size of `Foo`

```
src/metal/dynamic.hpp:14:24: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Foo'
   uint8_t memory[sizeof(T)] __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
```

Is it possible to workaround this 'incomplete type' error?

Or should I completly redesign the solution?

Comment: `class Foo` inherits from `class Interface` which is unknown because not fully declared. Try to declare `class Interface` (full declare with members) before declaring `class Foo`

Comment: @nikniknik2016 no that is not the real issue here, see my answer

Comment: @nikniknik2016  m.s is right. For the question purpose I simplify the code too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Foo` is not yet a complete type when `MemoryPool` is instantiated.

[clang's error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/519a61fe3fe2518d) is pretty specific:

```
main.cpp:10:24: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'Foo'
        uint8_t memory[sizeof(T)] __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
                       ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:31: note: in instantiation of member class 'MemoryPool<Foo, 8>::Pool' requested here

    static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(Pool)], size> memoryPool;
                              ^
main.cpp:35:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'MemoryPool<Foo, 8>' requested here
class Foo : public MemoryPool<Foo, 8>
                   ^
main.cpp:35:7: note: definition of 'Foo' is not complete until the closing '}'
class Foo : public MemoryPool<Foo, 8>
  ^
```

You can work around this issue by delaying the application `sizeof` until `Foo` is a complete type.

This can be done by accessing `memoryPool` through a static member function:

```
template<class T, unsigned size>
class MemoryPool
{
private:
    struct Pool
    {
        bool    allocated         __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
        uint8_t memory[sizeof(T)] __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
    };

    template <typename P>
    static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(P)], size>& getPool()
    {
        static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(P)], size> memoryPool;
        return memoryPool;
    }
public:
    void* operator new(std::size_t) noexcept
    {
        T* ret = nullptr;
        for(auto it = getPool<Pool>().begin(); it != getPool<Pool>().end(); ++it)
        {
           /* ... */
        } 
        return ret;
    }
};
```

**[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79267478d4ee3247)**

C++14 allows a slightly simpler implementation:

```
template<class T, unsigned size>
class MemoryPool
{
private:
    struct Pool
    {
        bool    allocated         __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
        uint8_t memory[sizeof(T)] __attribute__ ((aligned (sizeof(void*))));
    };

    static auto& getPool()
    {
        static std::array<uint8_t[sizeof(Pool)], size> memoryPool;
        return memoryPool;
    }
public:
    void* operator new(std::size_t) noexcept
    {
        T* ret = nullptr;
        for(auto it = getPool().begin(); it != getPool().end(); ++it)
        {
           /* ... */
        } 
        return ret;
    }
};
```

**[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78d75d98c742baa6)**